como crear un footer y un header con tabulator usando jspdf y autotables?
Necesito ayuda para poder recrear cierto pdf utilizando la libreria tabulator que es muy parecida a datatables, el problema recae a la hora de crear el header y el footer del documento. Dondo no se porque el header pasa para otra hoja o no lo estoy haciendo como deberia, ademas necesito hacer la paginacion del pdf ya que este tendra muchisimas paginas pero no se como hacerla y ninguna busqueda se refiere exactamente a tabulator sino a jspdf solamente. Adjunto mi codigo para que puedan apreciar mejor el problema.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="dist/css/tabulator.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Tabulator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div><button id="download-pdf">Download PDF</button></div>
    <div id="example-table"></div>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.1.4/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.1.4/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.4.0/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf-autotable/3.5.20/jspdf.plugin.autotable.min.js"></script>
<script>
     var tabledata = [
    {id:1, department:"Cultura",ident:"20100", identification_number:"00000000",name:"Oli Bob", last_name:"fuentes alvarez",col:"1000,00", dob:"300,00",bob:"200,00"},
    {id:2, department:"Cultura",ident:"20100", identification_number:"00000000",name:"Oli Bob", last_name:"fuentes alvarez",col:"1000,00", dob:"300,00",bob:"200,00"},
    {id:3, department:"recursos",ident:"20100", identification_number:"00000000",name:"Oli Bob", last_name:"fuentes alvarez",col:"1000,00", dob:"300,00",bob:"200,00"},
    {id:4, department:"informatica",ident:"20100", identification_number:"00000000",name:"Oli Bob", last_name:"fuentes alvarez",col:"1000,00", dob:"300,00",bob:"200,00"},
    {id:5, department:"Cultura",ident:"20100", identification_number:"00000000",name:"Oli Bob", last_name:"fuentes alvarez",col:"1000,00", dob:"300,00",bob:"200,00"},
    {id:6, department:"otros",ident:"20100", identification_number:"00000000",name:"Oli Bob", last_name:"fuentes alvarez",col:"1000,00", dob:"300,00",bob:"200,00"},
    {id:7, department:"informatica",ident:"20100", identification_number:"00000000",name:"Oli Bob", last_name:"fuentes alvarez",col:"1000,00", dob:"300,00",bob:"200,00"},
    {id:8, department:"informatica",ident:"20100", identification_number:"00000000",name:"Oli Bob", last_name:"fuentes alvarez",col:"1000,00", dob:"300,00",bob:"200,00"},
    {id:9, department:"Cultura",ident:"20100", identification_number:"00000000",name:"Oli Bob", last_name:"fuentes alvarez",col:"1000,00", dob:"300,00",bob:"200,00"},
    {id:10, department:"otros",ident:"20100", identification_number:"00000000",name:"Oli Bob", last_name:"fuentes alvarez",col:"1000,00", dob:"300,00",bob:"200,00"},
    {id:11, department:"informatica",ident:"20100", identification_number:"00000000",name:"Oli Bob", last_name:"fuentes alvarez",col:"1000,00", dob:"300,00",bob:"200,00"},
    {id:12, department:"otros",ident:"20100", identification_number:"00000000",name:"Oli Bob", last_name:"fuentes alvarez",col:"1000,00", dob:"300,00",bob:"200,00"},
    {id:13, department:"informatica",ident:"20100", identification_number:"00000000",name:"Oli Bob", last_name:"fuentes alvarez",col:"1000,00", dob:"300,00",bob:"200,00"},
    {id:14, department:"informatica",ident:"20100", identification_number:"00000000",name:"Oli Bob", last_name:"fuentes alvarez",col:"1000,00", dob:"300,00",bob:"200,00"},
    {id:15, department:"Cultura",ident:"20100", identification_number:"00000000",name:"Oli Bob", last_name:"fuentes alvarez",col:"1000,00", dob:"300,00",bob:"200,00"},
    {id:16, department:"otros",ident:"20100", identification_number:"00000000",name:"Oli Bob", last_name:"fuentes alvarez",col:"1000,00", dob:"300,00",bob:"200,00"},
    {id:18, department:"informatica",ident:"20100", identification_number:"00000000",name:"Oli Bob", last_name:"fuentes alvarez",col:"1000,00", dob:"300,00",bob:"200,00"},
    {id:19, department:"informatica",ident:"20100", identification_number:"00000000",name:"Oli Bob", last_name:"fuentes alvarez",col:"1000,00", dob:"300,00",bob:"200,00"},
    {id:20, department:"informatica",ident:"20100", identification_number:"00000000",name:"Oli Bob", last_name:"fuentes alvarez",col:"1000,00", dob:"300,00",bob:"200,00"},
    {id:21, department:"Cultura",ident:"20100", identification_number:"00000000",name:"Oli Bob", last_name:"fuentes alvarez",col:"1000,00", dob:"300,00",bob:"200,00"},
    {id:22, department:"otros",ident:"20100", identification_number:"00000000",name:"Oli Bob", last_name:"fuentes alvarez",col:"1000,00", dob:"300,00",bob:"200,00"},
    {id:23, department:"informatica",ident:"20100", identification_number:"00000000",name:"Oli Bob", last_name:"fuentes alvarez",col:"1000,00", dob:"300,00",bob:"200,00"},
    {id:24, department:"informatica",ident:"20100", identification_number:"00000000",name:"Oli Bob", last_name:"fuentes alvarez",col:"1000,00", dob:"300,00",bob:"200,00"},
    {id:25, department:"informatica",ident:"20100", identification_number:"00000000",name:"Oli Bob", last_name:"fuentes alvarez",col:"1000,00", dob:"300,00",bob:"200,00"},
    {id:26, department:"Cultura",ident:"20100", identification_number:"00000000",name:"Oli Bob", last_name:"fuentes alvarez",col:"1000,00", dob:"300,00",bob:"200,00"},
 ];

    //create Tabulator on DOM element with id "example-table"

const logoImage = 'data:image/png;base64,';

const logoImage2 = 'data:image/png;base64,';

var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    height:205, // set height of table (in CSS or here), this enables the Virtual DOM and improves render speed dramatically (can be any valid css height value)
    data:tabledata, //assign data to table
    layout:"fitColumns", //fit columns to width of table (optional)
    groupBy:"department",
    columns:[ //Define Table Columns
        {title:"Departamento", field:"department", width:150},
        {title:"Matricula", field:"ident",},
        {title:"Cedula", field:"identification_number", width:150},
        {title:"Nombre", field:"name", width:150},
        {title:"Apellido", field:"last_name", hozAlign:"left",},
        {title:"Asignaciones", field:"col"},
        {title:"Deducciones", field:"dob",},
        {title:"Saldo", field:"bob",},
    ],
});

document.getElementById("download-pdf").addEventListener("click", function(){

    var totalPagesExp = '{total_pages_count_string}'
    var self = this


    table.download("pdf", "data.pdf", {
    orientation:"portrait", //set page orientation to portrait

    autoTable:{ //advanced table styling

        styles: {
        
        },
     
        margin: {top: 200},
    },

    documentProcessing:function(doc){



    const headerY = 10;
    const footerY = doc.internal.pageSize.getHeight() - 650;

  // Add header text (centered)
  doc.setFontSize(24)
  doc.text('estatuto municipal', 140, 50,)
  doc.setFontSize(10)
  doc.text('Hasta:', 110, 90,)
  doc.text('Desde:', 180, 90,)
  doc.text('Semana:', 280, 90,)
  doc.text('Tipo de Nomina:', 110, 120,)
  doc.setFontSize(16)
  doc.text('Nomina por Departamento', 200, 180,)
  doc.setFontSize(11)
  doc.setTextColor(100)  
  doc.addImage(logoImage, 'JPEG', 40, 20, 50, 50);

    // Check if content extends to multiple pages
    if (doc.internal.getNumberOfPages() > 1) {
        // Add a new page if needed
        doc.addPage();
    }

 
    // Add logo image to footer (centered)
    doc.addImage(logoImage2, 'JPEG', 1, footerY, 650, 250,);
  
    function addFooters() {
    const pageCount = doc.internal.getNumberOfPages();
    for(var i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++) {
        doc.text(String(i), 196, 285);
            }                           
        }


    },



});
});


</script>
</html>



